# Python Good Integration of Pandas Dataframe in Overall Class Design

Tags: python-3.x, oop, pandas

I have a very short question regarding class design. My program uses a `Data` class to load various `pandas dataframes` as class attributes. There are also some getter methods. Additionally, I have another class which uses the data (approx. 150 MB) provided from the `Data` class as a class attribute. The `Foobar_Collection` class needs only one instance since it's job is to keep track of all `Foo` instances. Conceptually, it looks like this:

```
class Data(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.x = [1,2,3,4] #actually load a pandas dataframe here
   def getX(self,i):
      return self.x[i]

class Foobar_Collection(dict):
    data = Data()                                #### Is this okay? 
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kw):
        super(Foobar_Collection, self).__init__(*arg,**kw)
    def foobar(self,*arg,**kw):
        foo = Foo(*arg,**kw)
        self[foo.name] = foo
        return foo
    def run_myMethodForAllfoobars(self):
        for name in self:
            self[name].myMethod(10)
        return None  

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.num  = None
    def myMethod(self,i):
        self.num = Foobar_Collection.data.getX(i) #### Is this okay?
        return None 

#just to illustrate the purpose of Foobar_Collection                                                             
Foobar = Foobar_Collection()
Foobar.foobar('A')
Foobar.foobar('B')
```

It's working fine. I just wonder wether this is a good way "to integrate" the data? I would appreciate some comments about this design.